# Lotus Domino routing error

Tags: ibm-domino

When I send an email to any group it goes into a particular person inbox automatically.Please guide me.I am describing here like I have a group like name abc news and mail id is `<abcnews@xyz.com>` and another person is `<abc@xyz.com>`. So when I send email to group `<abcnews@xyz.com>` it automatically moves into `<abc@xyz.com>`. Kindly guide me.

Comment: Please add Server- Version and EXACT examples. I guess that SMTP_Left_Dot_Never_Domain=1 might help, but your description is very vague, so that I could be completely wrong... see this link: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=463&context=SSKTMJ&context=SSPQ69&context=SSKTWP&context=SSRNU3&context=SSRNUY&q1=mail+not+delivered+domain&q2=user&uid=swg21102170&loc=en_US&cs=utf-8&lang=en

Answer (score 1):

Inbound recipient lookups are controlled by the Address lookup setting on the Router/SMTP - Basics tab of the Configuration Settings document (global or server specific). This setting determines the criteria that the Router uses when attempting to match the SMTP address on an incoming message to an entry in the $Users view.
The settings for "Address lookup" are:

- Fullname then Local Part - (default) The Router first searches the Domino Directory for a match for the full Internet address (localpart@domain.com). If no match is found, it searches the directory again, looking for a match for the local part of the address only.
- Fullname only - The Router searches the Domino Directory for full Internet addresses only. For example, it searches for "user@domain.com" but not for "user." If an exact match is not found and the domain suffix is equivalent to an Internet domain alias defined in the Global domain document, a secondary search is performed using the domain suffix of the primary Internet domain.
- Local Part only - The Router searches the Domino Directory for a match of the local part of the Internet address, that is, the part before the @ symbol. Local part matching matches periods and underscores in the address with spaces in the directory.

See the [help](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.help.domino.admin.doc%2FDOC%2FH_ROUTING_MAIL_USING_NOTES_ROUTING_2689_OVER.html) for more details, especially the "Exhaustive lookup" option, but you will probably set this to "Fullname only" (watch out for side effects if you have several internet domains in place).

If that does not fix your problem, please specify in more detail, how the wrongly routed emails are sent, received and routed. See [Troubleshooting IBM Lotus Domino 8 mail routing issues](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/lotus/documentation/domino/d-ls-mailrouting/) for more tips on how you can debug this yourself.